# Not able to install GD module in Perl

Tags: perl, gd

I am not able to install GD module in PErl.
I have done CPAN GD but that gives me error:

```
Reading '/home/harsh/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 28 Sep 2020 02:17:03 GMT
Running install for module 'GD'
Checksum for /home/harsh/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RU/RURBAN/GD-2.73.tar.gz ok
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring R/RU/RURBAN/GD-2.73.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Notice: Type perl Makefile.PL -h for command-line option summary.

Package gdlib was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gdlib.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gdlib' found
 at Makefile.PL line 451.
*** can not find package gdlib
*** check that it is properly installed and available in PKG_CONFIG_PATH
 at Makefile.PL line 451.
Warning: No success on command[/home/harsh/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
  RURBAN/GD-2.73.tar.gz
  /home/harsh/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
```

and whenever I run my file it gives:

```
Can't locate GD.pm in @INC (you may need to install the GD module) (@INC contains: /home/harsh/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/lib/site_perl/5.28.0/x86_64-linux /home/harsh/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/lib/site_perl/5.28.0 /home/harsh/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/lib/5.28.0/x86_64-linux /home/harsh/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/lib/5.28.0) at generate_feedburner_graph.perl line 18.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at generate_feedburner_graph.perl line 18.
```

Also i have seen this solution of running sudo apt-get install libgd2-xpm-dev but this says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgd2-xpm-dev
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I believe `apt-get install libgd-perl` will install the module unless you want to go with `cpan[m]?` (https://askubuntu.com/questions/627304/cant-install-cpan-module-gd)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install `libgd-dev`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgd-dev
```

Comment: What if I'm using CentOS?